# oninput not working in Angular. Alternative?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-change

Im trying to create a function that reads the value of an input and triggers a series of true/false, however the code below keeps returning "passStrength is not defined."
From what I can find, oninput isn't supported by Angular. How can achieve this in Angular?

Within my controller:

```
$scope.passStrength = function(input) {
    if (input.value.toLowerCase().indexOf(/[a-z]/) > -1) {
        $scope.lwrChar = true;
        console.log('lower ' + $scope.lwrChar);
    } else if (input.value.toUpperCase().indexOf(/[A-Z]/) > -1) {
        $scope.uprChar = true;
        console.log('upper ' + $scope.uprChar);
    } else if (input.value.indexOf() == !isNaN(n)) {
        $scope.nbrChar = true;
        console.log('number ' + $scope.nbrChar);
    } else if (input.value.length >= 8) {
        $scope.countChar = true;
        console.log('count ' + $scope.countChar);
    }
};
```

and in my markup:

```
<input id="password" oninput="passStrength()" />
```

Comment: The answer is in your tags: ng-change. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To fire an event when the input changes, use ng-change. Also, you must define a ng-model.

```
<input ng-model="password" ng-change="passStrength(password)" />
```

Edit:
Created a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/ybvmeYDwvNAv4W5QeNum?p=preview) demonstrating it

Comment: Thanks but then how do I refer to the model in the controller? replacing input with $scope.password doesnt do the trick. Im getting an undefined error from the function for input.

Comment: Take a look at this [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/ybvmeYDwvNAv4W5QeNum?p=preview).

Comment: Thanks! I took a slightly different path but essentially the same!

Comment: Maybe it's worth mentioning that `ng-change` won't evaluate the expression whenever the model changes, but whenever it's changed by the user using the input field.

Comment: `onchange` and `oninput` are not the same, because `onchange` only fires when the field loses focus. While this answer may solve the OP's problem, it doesn't actually answer his question.

Comment: I was talking about `ng-change`, not `onchange`, and it answers his question well, as in title `oninput not working in Angular. Alternative?`