# Why does the oninput event behave differently in Angular than it does in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I'm learning Angular with TypeScript, and a few inconsistencies with JavaScript are troubling me. Here's a function which works perfectly with pure JavaScript (it programmatically sets `min` and `max` attributes to an input - please don't ask me [why I'd want to do that programmatically](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-framework/issues/20163)):

```js
function change_number(input,min,max) {
  if(input.value > max)
    input.value = max;
  else if(input.value < min)
    input.value = min;
}
```

```html
<input type='number' oninput='change_number(this,1,5)' placeholder='Enter a number' />
```

In Angular and TypeScript, the function behaves strangely: If I enter `10` into the input field, it doesn't reset to `5`, until I enter another digit, meaning the value is only read **after** the `input` event (and not *on*-input - don't know if that makes sense). What's more strange is it works fine with the `keydown` and `keyup` events. Why this behaviour? Is it linked to the way Angular binds events to inputs? I have a feeling understanding this would help me better understand Angular's binding mechanism with `NgModel`

FYI, here's how I called the function in Angular (using the Ionic Framework) - I used the bound `quantity` in `[(ngModel)]` as the value of the input:

```
<ion-input type='number' (input)='change_numbers(1,5)' [(ngModel)]='quantity'></ion-input>
```

Comment: The this parameter seems redundant. Also the min and max can be attributes rather than you manually setting the value. https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_type_number.asp

Comment: (input)='change_numbers(1,5) , here you should pass 3 arguments right ?

Comment: @TechnoTech not necessary since you can get the value of the input through `[(ngModel)]. @John, please see my link on why I'm doing it programmatically and not using attributes. It doesn't work in Angualr, been reported as a bug, but I'm not sure

Comment: yes thats, right, i thought you are using the same  function. Let me check and i will create a link for your solution

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Angular framework is behaving perfectly the way it has to**. It is us who are a bit confused.

Angular handles forms in a bit different manner. There are two approaches to build forms in angular -

- Reactive (Synchronous)
- Template-driven (Asynchronous)

The Key difference between them is the above **Sync/async behaviour**. In simple terms we can say that.

- Synchronous - during the data change.
- Asynchronous - after the data has changed.

x

```
<ion-input type='number' (input)='change_numbers(1,5)' [(ngModel)]='quantity'></ion-input>
```

Above one is a Template-driven approach. Here we are using `[(ngModel)]`, this updates only after the data has changed.

In order to make a reactive input field, use below code :-

in app.component.ts file

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';
import { debounceTime, distinctUntilChanged } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Component({
  selector: 'dd-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent {

  form: FormGroup;
  min = 0;
  max = 5;

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.buildForm();
  }

  buildForm(): void {
    this.form = this.fb.group({
      numberInput: ''
    });

    this.form.get('numberInput').valueChanges.pipe(distinctUntilChanged()).subscribe(_ => {
      if (_) {

        if (_ > this.max) {
          this.form.get('numberInput').setValue(5);
        }
        if (_ < this.min) {
          this.form.get('numberInput').setValue(0);
        }

      } else {
        this.form.get('numberInput').reset('');
      }
    });
  }
}
```

In app.html (Here i am posting 2 way to express it.)

```
  <form [formGroup]="form">
    <!-- <input type='number' [min]='0' [max]='5' formControlName="numberInput" /> we can also this one, more easy just set value dynamically -->
    <input type='number' formControlName="numberInput" />
  </form>
```

NOTE:- DONT FORGET TO IMPORT **ReactiveFormsModule**

More about forms can found in the official docs : -https://angular.io/guide/forms-overview

Comment: Your given code works perfectly in plain Javascript. But in angular, forms are handled a bit differently.

Comment: If still confused, let me know.

Comment: seems a little bit cumbersome. If I have to go through all this just to get a JavaScript-like behaviour, I'm wondering, what additional benefit does Angular get from sort of reinventing the wheel? Thanks for the clarification though

Comment: It might be cumbersome at first look. Even I felt the same in my earlier days. But only we start dealing the real-world issues regarding froms. All this becomes easy.

Comment: The main benefit that Angular gets - is modular/reusable code which are testable and easy to expand functionality.

Answer (score 3):

To understand why it behaves like that, first you need to be familiar with two basic concepts:

1. A "banana in the box" syntax `[(ngModel)]="quantity"` is nothing more than sugar syntax which is translated to `[ngModel]="quantity" (ngModelChange)="quantity = $event"`
2. In angular, change detection is by default triggered at the end of the call stack (this is possible with zone.js).

With this knowledge, you can understand what really happens here:

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-agm1ty?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

1. You type 4 into the input.
2. `onNgModelChange` is triggered, `quantity` is set to `4`. The inner [model](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/forms/src/directives/ng_model.ts#L176) value of `input` (more specifically, `ngModel` directive) is still equal to `undefined`.
3. `change_numbers` is called, `quantity` is not changed.
4. This is the end of the callstack (note that `ngModelChange` and `change_numbers` all called in a single callstack due to how angular handles events). Change detection is performed. Because `quantity` (`4` now) is bound to the `ngModel` (`undefined` now), angular detects a need to update the UI (because `undefined != 4` of course).
5. Update is performed, everything works as expected.

---

6. You type the next number - `8`.
7. `onNgModelChange` is triggered, `quantity` is set to `48`. The inner [model](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/forms/src/directives/ng_model.ts#L176) value of `input` (more specifically, `ngModel` directive) is still equal to `4`.
8. `change_numbers` is called, `quantity` is changed to `5`.
9. This is the end of the callstack. Change detection is performed. Because `quantity` (`5` now) is bound to the `ngModel` (`4` now), angular detects a need to update the UI (because `5 != 4` of course).
10. Update is performed, everything works as expected.

---

11. You type the next number - `7`.
12. `onNgModelChange` is triggered, `quantity` is set to `57`. The inner [model](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/forms/src/directives/ng_model.ts#L176) value of `input` (more specifically, `ngModel` directive) is still equal to `5`.
13. `change_numbers` is called, `quantity` is changed to `5`.
14. This is the end of the callstack. Change detection is performed. Because `quantity` (`5` now) is bound to the `ngModel` (also `5` now), angular doesn't detect a need to update the UI (because `5 == 5` of course).
15. Update is not performed, UI remains stale.

---

A solution to that might be calling `detectChanges` in `onNgModelChange` method. It will work, because in this moment we will update the inner `model` value of `ngModel` (even if it is much higher than `5`). So even if we next decrease the value to `5`, angular still will detect a need to update the UI.

I hope that explains everything. If you'll have some questions, don't hesitate to let me know. Cheers!

Comment: I had this exact same problem, and i've been trying to find a solution for hours (I'm quite a rookie in angular). Thank you so much man, big upvote!

Comment: I've been through that too! Glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

Try this out, this works well, let me know if this is not what you want to achieve

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-z8xvkl)

html

```
<input type='number' (change)='change_numbers(1,5)' [(ngModel)]="quantity">
```

javascript

```
  change_numbers(min,max) {
   if(this.quantity > max)
     this.quantity = max;
   else if(this.quantity < min)
     this.quantity= min;
 }
```

Comment: Your code works `onChange`, not `oninput`, which is my problem, and not even `onkeydown` or `onkeyup`

Comment: @che-azeh - This works if I make it ``<input type='number' (input)='change_numbers(1,5)' [(ngModel)]="quantity">``

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this helps, but I found these;

[how to use oninput in Angular?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55480231/how-to-use-oninput-in-angular)

[oninput not working in Angular. Alternative?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36508578/oninput-not-working-in-angular-alternative)

They seem to talk a lot about using `(input)`; if you've tried it?

Reading on google about this issue, it just seems like if you're using Angular you have to do things "*The Angular Way*" or oddities like what you're trying to seek an answer for occur.

As Kuiil from The Mandolorian says; "This is the way"